# Call a C++ class method without a class instance?

Tags: c++, class, methods, instance, call

Long story short, I am trying to build a wrapper to access C++ source code from a C main function (I have to do the conversion because of Embedded systems); however, I am having trouble calling the methods from the class to an external function without creating an instance of that class.

I want to pass this `*side` pointer from my C code, calculate the cube of it, and get returned the cubed value. I have tested my wrapper with simple pointer functions and variables and it works perfectly fine, however I am having trouble with class methods. Here is my source code to that, with the mistake I am making on the last line...:

```
class Cube
{
public:
    static int getVolume(int *side)
    {
        return *side * *side * *side;     //returns volume of cube
    }
};

void Cube_C(int *side) 
{
    return Cube.getVolume(*side);
}
```

Comment: Why is side an `int*` instead of just an `int`?

Comment: Hello! It is an int* because I am inputting a the value from C. My C code looks like this: 

`int cubeSide = 5;
 printf("Cube of 5 is: %d\n\n", GetVolume_C(&cubeSide));`


In the meantime I use `extern"C"` on a header file to link the C with C++.

Comment: I still don't see why you need to send it as a pointer instead of a plain `int`? If you check my example in the answer I gave, there are no pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call a `static` member function of a class without an instance: just add the class name followed by the [scope resolution operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator) (`::`) before the member function's name (rather than the class member operator, `.`, as you have tried).

Also, in your `Cube_C` function, you should *not* dereference the `side` pointer, as the `getVolume` function takes a `int *` pointer as its argument. And you need to declare the return type of that function as an `int` (not `void`):

```cpp
int Cube_C(int *side) 
{
    return Cube::getVolume(side);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already tried that soultion however I still get an error of my return value not matching the function type .

Comment: @PolarBear Oops - my mistake (see edited answer). I forgot the second correction to your `Cube_C` function!

Answer (score 2):

For this particular example, you don't need them to be classes at all since `Cube` doesn't hold a state. Just make a function:

```
int Cube_Volume(int side) { return side * side * side; }
```

If you want objects that holds a state to be reusable from C, you do need an instance:

```
class Cube {
public:
    Cube(int side) : m_side(side) {}
    int getVolume() const { return m_side * m_side * m_side; }

private:
    int m_side;
};
```

Then in your C interface:

```
extern "C" int Cube_Volume(int side) { return Cube(side).getVolume(); }
```

Edit: I added a more verbose example at [github](https://github.com/TedLyngmo/C_calling_Cpp) to show how you can create C functions to create and manipulate C++ objects.

Comment: Wow thanks for this answer. I really need to study more of C++ to understand what is happening here but could be very useful for my future! (sorry that I cannot upvote... to new in stack overflow)

Comment: @PolarBear That's ok :-) What happens in the part with the C++ class is that `Cube(side)` instantiates a temporary object with the `side` set to whatever the user calls `Cube_Volume` with. It then calls `getVolume()` on that temporary object. The object is then automatically destroyed. When optimized, this will likely just be doing `side * side * side` directly.

Comment: @PolarBear I started a github project (see update in the answer) that I'll probably expand on in the future. It contains just one example of a C++ class and C functions to create an object, call the object's member functions and then destroy it.

Comment: Thanks a lot on that matter. I will keep posting questions regarding that topic. Next useful expansion suggestions in case you will continue expanding would be template classes and dynamic (heap) memory allocation in a dynamic array from C++ to C.

Comment: @PolarBear You're welcome! If I remember correctly, I've made a class-like set of C functions for dynamic memory management in an answer here, but that was in pure C. For C++ one could simply create a wrapper for `std::vector<>` for the specific types one wants to store. Since templates doesn't exist in C one would have to make an explicit instantiation for each type.